# Why am I getting invalid identifier error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have already created two tables without issue. They are:

```
CREATE TABLE region
( 
     regionid CHAR NOT NULL,
     regionname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (regionid) 
);

CREATE TABLE store
( 
     storeid VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
     storezip CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     regionid CHAR NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (storeid),
     FOREIGN KEY (regionid) REFERENCES region(regionid) 
);
```

However, when I try to enter the following table I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE employee  
( 
     employeeid VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,  
     firstN CHAR(25) NOT NULL,  
     lastN CHAR(25) NOT NULL,  
     PRIMARY KEY (employeeid),
     FOREIGN KEY (storeid) REFERENCES store(storeid) 
);
```

The error I am getting is:

> ORA-00904: "storeid": invalid identifier

Why am I getting this error? Thank you

Comment: Missing comma before `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: I edited the original code and added the missing comma but I still get the same error.

Comment: With Oracle, use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
FOREIGN KEY (storeid) REFERENCES store(storeid)
```

But you have not declared `storeid`.  You need to declare it before you can specify that it is a foreign key.

Other notes:

- Don't use `char` without a length.  If it is one character, declare it as such.
- I think id columns should be numeric rather than strings.
- Don't use `char()` when you should be using `varchar2()`.  `char()` pads the value out with spaces, and that is usually undesirable.

Comment: storeid is already declared in the store table. Do I also have to declare it in the employee tables as well?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I should have CREATE TABLE employee  
( employeeid VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,  
firstN CHAR(25) NOT NULL,  
lastN CHAR(25) NOT NULL, storeid VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (employeeid),
FOREIGN KEY (storeid) REFERENCES store(storeid) 
);  Thanks you!

Comment: Yes, a foreign key is a column which references a second column, and both columns need to be declared.